# Android assableRelease build size difference on linux and windows machines

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I have tried to setup a CI system for the android app.

When I work on my Windows machine and create a signed APK I get the size of **3948 KB** (from Android Studio).

But when I do it from the linux system (CI system) I get the APK size **3974 KB**.

So, I don't understand why I am getting the difference. I am using the same SDKs on both the platform.

SDKs on both platform:

- SDK Tools r25.2.3
- Google Repository, revision 40
- SDK Platform Android 7.1.1, API 25, revision 2
- Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 25.0.1
- Android Support Repository, revision 40
- Google Play services, revision 38

Any idea what can cause this little difference?

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: have you opened both apk-s with a zip-file browser and compared the contained -files?

Comment: Nop, I just compared the checksum and saw difference. So I checked the sizes. I should definitely do that.

Comment: @k3b I see diff in dex file. See my updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I analyzed those ap in Android Studio, I found that the difference was in the png files. On my windows machine pngs were 8x8 bit pngs. But on Linux machine it was 16x16 bit pngs. So due to this, it slightly increased the size on linux.

However, this got fixed in the next update. I got the same md5. But, with another update, I got different md5. So, I checked again and it didn't had any file size difference. Just the md5. I tested both apks, and both were fine. No issues.

So, it may be just a bit different, but there is no code difference. So, I am fine with this (*as of now!*).